# Ability to capture a video and uploading it into server in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

As I am newbie to the Iphone Sdk I dont know how to Capture the video from our Iphone and upload the captured video to the Server.

Guys please suggest me how to go through this with sample code.

Thanks in advance,
Monish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 2 step process: capture video and then uploading the video

1/ Capture video, you can use UIImagePickerController

[This is a good tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2009/07/28/getting-images-from-the-iphone-photo-library-or-camera-using-uiimagepickercontroller/) for choosing photo/video from library or camera

2/ Upload Video, you need to take out the data and then upload it

After you capture a video, you will be returned a NSURL *url.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)mediaDict {


    NSString *type = [mediaDict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] || 
        [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) { // movie != video
        NSURL *url = [mediaDict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        // UPLOAD THIS DATA
    }
    return nil;
  }
```